# HTML5 custom pattern validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a validation for input with 3 letters at the beginning of the string, then a comma, then space and then some words.

For example: Coz, You are genius

I am using this pattern for that purpose,
`pattern="^[a-zA-Z]{3}[,]{1}[a-zA-Z]{30}"`
alse tried this pattern `^[a-zA-Z]{3}[, ][a-zA-Z\s]`

Below is my javascript for custom validation.

```
    var data = document.getElementById('sentence');
        data.addEventListener('invalid', function (e) {
            //console.log(data.validity);
            if (data.validity.patternMismatch) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("Please choose from dropdown");
            } else if (!data.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("This is not a valid sentence");
            }
            data.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity('');
            });
        }, false);
```

I guess I am missing pattern for space after comma and space in words.

Comment: You need to account for spaces as well.

Comment: I don't think browser's pattern attribute fully support regex yet, but your regex should be closer to `^[A-Za-z]{3},\s(\w+\s?)+`   https://regex101.com/r/HOURbf/1

Comment: @bassxzero Thanks buddy, that worked pretty well. I think you should put your comment as an answer with a little more explanation so that I can accept it.  :)

Comment: @Abhimanu answer created, glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think browser's pattern attribute fully support regex yet, but your regex should be closer to `^[A-Za-z]{3},\s(\w+\s?)+`.

The link below does a great job of explaining the regex, but here is a breakdown.

`^[A-Za-z]{3}` start with 3 characters

`,\s` followed by a comma and a space

`(\w+\s?)+` followed by a group of a word and then an optional space. The `+` just means the word-space group must appear one or more times.

E.G

[regex101.com/r/HOURbf/1](https://regex101.com/r/HOURbf/1)